# Professional way to state the purpose of a letter

Tags: word-choice, sentence, letter-writing, professions

I'm writing a letter to a professor. It is my intention to state the purpose of the letter in the prescript, such as:

> This is about project FOO you assigned on date BAR.

But I think this would seem unprofessional. What would be a more proper way to state 'this letter is about xyz'?

Comment: Define *unprofessional* or *professional*. Unclear or primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @Drew er... used for professional purposes, or in professional settings?

Comment: Such as? What do you mean by those, exactly? There are all kinds of "professional purposes" and "professional settings" (and all kinds of professors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For very formal, I suggest "in re", which is used in legal proceedings to reference the subject of the case.
https://definitions.uslegal.com/i/in-re/
For example, 
Dear Professor,

In re Project Foo which you assigned on date BAR, ...

Alternatively, you could just use "Re:" with this format:

Professor John Doe
[Address]

[Date]
Re: Project FOO assigned on date BAR

Dear Professor, 
With reference to the above project...

Comment: although on date "BAR" confuses me. I assumed that was an internal notation or abbreviation known to you and the professor.

Comment: Apologies, I'm a computer programmer and I automatically use foo and bar as placeholder names. For reference, see: [Foobar - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar)

Comment: Thanks - love learning new things. If you use the second format, place a hard return afte the date. For some reason that got wiped when I posted.